# How to switch between login page and app with Aurelia

Tags: javascript, aurelia

I'm using the Aurelia skeleton for my project. Everything seemed so intuitive, however I'm stuck with a problem which I suspect is fairly easy (if you know how).

The problem is that the app.html / app.js is initially showing a nav bar and loading some default styles.

Now I need a login page, which does not load anything but its own styles, no navbar no nothing - just its own login form.

So I tried something like this:

**app.js**

```html
<template>
    <div if.bind="auth.isNotAuthenticated()">
        <require from="components/login/index" ></require>
        <login router.bind="router"></login>
    </div> 
    <div if.bind="auth.isAuthenticated()">
        <require from="nav-bar.html" ></require>
        <require from="../styles/styles.css"></require>
        <div class="container" id="banner">
            <div class="row">
                <img src="images/logo.png" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <nav-bar router.bind="router"></nav-bar>
        <div class="page-host">
            <router-view></router-view>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>
```

Obviously that doesn't work (unless you refresh the page/f5), since the app.js / app.html is the root route which is always present and never changes. But I hope the logic within the markup helps illustrate what I'm looking to solve?

I guess my if only I knew how to reload the parent route (app.js) when I navigate from the login route, on login success, to another route. And again when I logout, the parent route (app.js) should be refreshed as well once again. Then all my problems would be solved.

What am I missing here? :-)

Answer (score 37, accepted):

I think aurelia's `setRoot(module)` function will help with this.

Here's the standard `main.js` file that "bootstraps" the aurelia app:

**main.js**

```js
export function configure(aurelia) {
  aurelia.use
    .standardConfiguration()
    .developmentLogging();

  aurelia.start()
    .then(a => a.setRoot()); // this is the equivalent of setRoot('app')
}
```

When `setRoot` is called with no arguments Aurelia looks for an app.js + app.html viewmodel and view.

We can adjust the logic to check whether the user is logged in and if not, show the login screen:

**main.js**

```js
export function configure(aurelia) {
  aurelia.use
    .standardConfiguration()
    .developmentLogging();

  aurelia.start()
    .then(a => {
      if (userIsLoggedIn()) {
        a.setRoot('app');
      } else {
        a.setRoot('login');
      }
    });
}
```

Then in your login view model you can call `setRoot('app')` after the user has successfully logged in:

**login.js**

```js
import {Aurelia, inject} from 'aurelia-framework';
import {AuthService} from './my-auth-service';

@inject(Aurelia, AuthService)
export class Login {
  userName = '';
  password = '';

  constructor(aurelia, authService) {
    this.aurelia = aurelia;
    this.authService = authService;
  }

  submit() {
    // attempt to login and if successful, launch the app view model.
    this.authService.login(userName, password)
      .then(() => this.aurelia.setRoot('app'));
  }
}
```

*Note: if your app includes a "logout" feature that will send the user back to the login screen (eg `setRoot('login')`), be sure to [reset the router](https://github.com/aurelia/framework/issues/590#issuecomment-244078830) and update the url accordingly. This will prevent issues when the user signs back in. More details in [here](https://github.com/aurelia/framework/issues/590) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38120388/aurelia-switching-between-app-roots-with-different-route-configurations/).*

Comment: Thank alot for the amazing answer! setRoot was indeed the way to go!

Comment: @jeremy-danyow, when I call `setRoot` after authentication, aurelia loads the js module and corresponding HTML but does not render anything on the page. If I hit refresh at this point, everything loads fine. Is there any missing piece in the above code?

Comment: Dude.....I can't believe I never thought of this. This is genius, and now I'm facepalming at all the stupid hacks I've done to make this work in an equivalent way....

Comment: Ha- glad it was helpful!

Comment: Hi, where do I get the userUserIsLoggedIn() function from in main.js? I would like to call the global authentication service, but don't know how to get the instance in main.js.

Comment: in `main.js` you can use `aurelia.container.get(MyService)` to retrieve services that you would normally reference using `@inject(MyService)`

Comment: For anyone using this, be aware that you might run into this issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38120388/aurelia-switching-between-app-roots-with-different-route-configurations/

Answer (score 4):

For a working example of setRoot you can check also 
https://foursails.github.io/sentry
https://github.com/foursails/sentry