# Hidden router view breaks databinding - Aurelia

Tags: javascript, web-component, aurelia

I would like to conditionally show a login page, but encountered an issue. I reproduced it with the the official [aurelia skeleton application](https://github.com/aurelia/skeleton-navigation) by changing `app.html` to the following:

```
<template>
  <require from="nav-bar.html"></require>
  <require from="bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css"></require>

  <nav-bar router.bind="router"></nav-bar>

  <template if.bind="false">
    <div class="page-host">
      <router-view></router-view>
    </div>
  </template>
  <h1 if.bind="true">Not logged in, show login page</h1>
</template>
```

The problem is that the router object no longer is defined, and therefore the navbar doesn't work (no navigation items are shown). Someone knows what I am doing wrong here?

Comment: it is very hard to know what's going on there. You should provide more information about what your app is doing. Take a look at Aurelia Docs at http://aurelia.io/docs.html#/aurelia/framework/1.0.0-beta.1.0.3/doc/article/cheat-sheet and search for "Customizing the Navigation Pipeline". I believe it will help you

Comment: You are right. I clarified now that I am using the official aurelia skeleton application and that above is a what I changed to reproduce the issue. I don't want to use the navigation pipeline as my idea was to handle login without redirects (this might be flawed in itself (?) but should work).

Comment: It tried your code here, and it works fine... perhaps there is another thing that is breaking your app. Provide the full app.js code, including the .js of the current route

Comment: I used the official skeleton linked above so the code is no different from that. Can you try once more as I updated the code somewhat, the issue I see is that no navigation items are displayed.

Comment: It seems that if you remove `<router-view>`, the `router` does not work. You should use a different approach to handle the login.

Comment: Too bad, I kind of came to the same conclusion however. Make it an answer and I'll accept it.

Comment: @SimonBengtsson use [`setRoot`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33458652/725866)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that if you remove `<router-view>`, the `router` does not work. You should use a different approach to handle the login.

Take a look at Aurelia Docs at http://aurelia.io/docs.html#/aurelia/framework/1.0.0-beta.1.0.3/doc/article/cheat-sheet and search for "Customizing the Navigation Pipeline".
I believe it will help you

**EDIT**

According to Jeremy Danyow's comment, the `setRoot(module)` function would be an easier solution. More information at https://stackoverflow.com/a/33458652/725866

Comment: I ended up using the customized navigation pipeline linked to above. However my goal from the start was to avoid having a login route as I don't think that make sense and complicates coding. I failed with this and pretty much gave up.

Comment: [`setRoot`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33458652/725866) would be easier than plugging into the nav pipeline

Comment: @JeremyDanyow that's true! Thank you for the comment. I'll update the answer with your link, to help future people!

Comment: @JeremyDanyow That was indeed what I was looking for and better expressed in that question!