# Rebuilding routes after refresh

Tags: javascript, aurelia, aurelia-auth

I'm having a bit of trouble getting some routing stuff working in Aurelia.

When a user goes to my app, if they have previously **authenticated**, I want to redirect them to a landing page. If not, direct to a login page.

I have the authenticated user redirect working fine (app.js -> login.js -> setupnav.js -> landing page).

The problem I have now is:

- When a user refreshes a page (`http://localhost:8088/aurelia-app/#/landing`), the `landing` route doesn't exist anymore and an error is thrown in the console (`ERROR [app-router] Error: Route not found: /landing(…)`). I would like to direct the user to `login` if a route cannot be found.

**Does anybody know how I can redirect a user from a missing route to my `login` page?**

Also any comments on how I set the routing up is welcome.

app.js

```
import {inject} from 'aurelia-framework';
import {Router} from 'aurelia-router';
import {FetchConfig} from 'aurelia-auth';
import {AuthorizeStep} from 'aurelia-auth';
import {AuthService} from 'aurelia-auth';

@inject(Router,FetchConfig, AuthService )
export class App {

    constructor(router, fetchConfig, authService){
        this.router = router;
        this.fetchConfig = fetchConfig;
        this.auth = authService;
    }

    configureRouter(config, router){
        config.title = 'VDC Portal';
        config.addPipelineStep('authorize', AuthorizeStep); // Add a route filter to the authorize extensibility point.
        config.map([
          { route: ['','login'], name: 'login',      moduleId: './login',      nav: false, title:'Login' },
          { route: '', redirect: "login" },
          { route: 'setupnav', name: 'setupnav',      moduleId: './setupnav',   nav: false, title:'setupnav' , auth:true}

        ]);
        this.router = router;

    }

    activate(){
        this.fetchConfig.configure();
    }

    created(owningView: View, myView: View, router){
        /* Fails to redirect user
        if(this.auth.isAuthenticated()){
            console.log("App.js ConfigureRouter: User already authenticated..");
            this.router.navigate("setupnav");
        }
        */
    }
}
```

login.js

```
import {AuthService} from 'aurelia-auth';
import {inject} from 'aurelia-framework';
import {Router} from 'aurelia-router';
@inject(AuthService, Router)

export class Login{
    constructor(auth, router){
        this.auth = auth;
        this.router = router;

        if(this.auth.isAuthenticated()){
            console.log("Login.js ConfigureRouter: User already authenticated..");
            this.router.navigate("setupnav");
        }
    };

    heading = 'Login';

    email='';
    password='';
    login(){
        console.log("Login()...");

        return this.auth.login(this.email, this.password)
        .then(response=>{
            console.log("success logged");
            console.log(response);
        })
        .catch(err=>{
            console.log("login failure");
        });
    };
}
```

Redirecting to:

setupnav.js

```
import {Router} from 'aurelia-router';
import {inject} from 'aurelia-framework';

@inject(Router)
export class Setupnav{

    theRouter = null;

    constructor(router){
        console.log("build setupnav. router:" + this.theRouter);   
        this.theRouter = router
    };

    activate()
    {     
        this.theRouter.addRoute( { route: 'landing', name: 'landing', moduleId: 'landing', nav: true, title:'Integration Health' , auth:true});
        this.theRouter.addRoute( { route: 'tools', name: 'tools', moduleId: 'tools', nav: true, title:'Integration Tools' , auth:true});
        this.theRouter.refreshNavigation();
        this.theRouter.navigate("landing");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To map an unknown route to a specific page, use the `mapUnknownRoutes` feature:

```js
configureRouter(config, router) {
  ...
  config.mapUnknownRoutes(instruction => {
    return 'login';
  });
}
```

That said, it might be easier to keep all auth related logic out of routing and instead use `setRoot` to set the appropriate root module depending on the user's auth state.

A standard `main.js` looks like this:

**main.js**

```js
export function configure(aurelia) {
  aurelia.use
    .standardConfiguration()
    .developmentLogging();

  aurelia.start().then(a => a.setRoot());
}
```

You could change the logic to something like this:

**main.js**

```js
export function configure(aurelia) {
  aurelia.use
    .standardConfiguration()
    .developmentLogging();

  aurelia.start().then(() => {
    if (userIsAuthenticated) {
      return aurelia.setRoot('app');
    }
    if (userPreviouslyAuthenticated) {
      return aurelia.setRoot('login');
    }
    return aurelia.setRoot('landing');
  });
}
```

In the example above, the `app` module is the only module that would configure routes.  The `login` module would be a login page which called `setRoot('app')` once the user was successfully logged in.  The `landing` page would call `setRoot('login')` when the user clicked the link/button.

Here's an answer to a related question that might be helpful:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/33458652/725866

Comment: `config.mapUnknownRoutes` was exactly what I was looking for, thanks! I'm using the [aurelia-auth](https://github.com/paulvanbladel/aurelia-auth) plugin so I don't think I can use it within `main.js`..

Comment: you should change `router.navigate('login');` to `return 'login';` or you will get an error in the console. I tried editing your post but it was rejected :P

Comment: I think it was rejected because there's a typo in your edit.  Let me see if I can fix it.