# Aurelia Route History

Tags: aurelia

How does one tell the router to ignore history for a particular view, for example when moving from a login view to the landing page, I want the login view not to appear in the navigation history (user must not be able to press the back button to the login view)
Similarly, if a user hits a page, and is redirected to the login view because the page requires authentication (this is currently done via pipeline step), the history should be maintained less the loginView.

Comment: I think this is related http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33458274/how-to-switch-between-login-page-and-app-with-aurelia?rq=1

Comment: yeah... my scenario is a little more complex than just the startup logic for aurelia. The current solution I've settled on is to add a pipeline step that checks the authenticated flag, and if not authenticated - navigates to login instead. Hence the "replace" requirement, because once authenticated, the navigation stack needs to be restored to exclude any reference to the login view. see https://github.com/SpoonX/aurelia-authentication/blob/master/src/authorizeStep.js for implementation

Answer (score 3):

Ok - found a potential solution using:

```
router.navigateToRoute(route, params, {trigger: true, replace: true}
```

when navigating to the new page after the LoginView.
The key is the **replace: true** parameter - which replaces the previous view in the history.