# How do I correctly import/inject aurelia to use 'setRoot'?

Tags: javascript, dependency-injection, aurelia

I am trying to set up an app with two "shells", one for login and one for the app after authentication. I am following the example outlined here kindly provided by Mathew James Davis, https://foursails.github.io/sentry, also shown in this question [How to switch between login page and app with Aurelia](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33458274/how-to-switch-between-login-page-and-app-with-aurelia).

My code is below. I get the error shown below. I think I am not using import and injection of {Aurelia} from 'aurelia-framework', but I cannot figure out the error.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

**In main.js**

```
import {AuthService} from './auth-service';

export function configure(aurelia) {
  aurelia.use
    .standardConfiguration()
    .feature('resources');

  aurelia.use.developmentLogging(environment.debug ? 'debug' : 'warn');

  if (environment.testing) {
    aurelia.use.plugin('aurelia-testing');
  }


  aurelia.start().then(() => {
    var auth = aurelia.container.get(AuthService);
      let root = auth.isLoggedIn() ? 'app' : 'login';
    aurelia.setRoot(root);
  });
}
```

**In login.js**

```
import { inject, Aurelia } from 'aurelia-framework';
import {AuthService} from './auth-service';

@inject(AuthService, Aurelia)
export class login {
    constructor(authService, aurelia) {
        this.auth = authService;
        this.app = aurelia;
    }

    login(){
        this.auth.login();
        this.app.setRoot('app');
    }

}
```

**In app.js**

```
import { inject, Aurelia } from 'aurelia-framework';
import AuthService from 'auth-service';

@inject(AuthService, Aurelia)
export class App {
  constructor(authService, aurelia){
    this.auth = authService;
    this.app= aurelia;
  }

  logout(){
    this.auth.logout();
    this.app.setRoot('login');
  }
}
```

In auth-service.js (just mock up for now)

```
 export class AuthService {



    constructor(){
        this.userLoggedIn = false;

    }

    login() {
        this.userLoggedIn = true;
    }

    logout(){
        this.userLoggedIn = false;
    }

    isLoggedIn(){
        return this.userLoggedIn;
    }

}
```

When I start the app, it shows the 'login' view as expected. It has a button which calls login(). I expect this function to then run this.app.setRoot('app'). However I get the following error:

```
aurelia-pal.js:37 Uncaught (in promise) Error: Error invoking App. Check the inner error for details.
------------------------------------------------
Inner Error:
Message: key/value cannot be null or undefined. Are you trying to inject/register something that doesn't exist with DI?
Inner Error Stack:
Error: key/value cannot be null or undefined. Are you trying to inject/register something that doesn't exist with DI?
    at validateKey (http://localhost:9000/scripts/vendor-bundle.js:54152:11)
    at Container.get (http://localhost:9000/scripts/vendor-bundle.js:54356:5)
    at Object.invoke (http://localhost:9000/scripts/vendor-bundle.js:54214:31)
    at InvocationHandler.invoke (http://localhost:9000/scripts/vendor-bundle.js:54172:166)
    at Container.invoke (http://localhost:9000/scripts/vendor-bundle.js:54443:23)
    at StrategyResolver.get (http://localhost:9000/scripts/vendor-bundle.js:53805:36)
    at Container.get (http://localhost:9000/scripts/vendor-bundle.js:54382:21)
    at http://localhost:9000/scripts/vendor-bundle.js:70122:71
End Inner Error Stack
------------------------------------------------

    at new AggregateError (http://localhost:9000/scripts/vendor-bundle.js:57264:11)
    at Container.invoke (http://localhost:9000/scripts/vendor-bundle.js:54445:13)
    at StrategyResolver.get (http://localhost:9000/scripts/vendor-bundle.js:53805:36)
    at Container.get (http://localhost:9000/scripts/vendor-bundle.js:54382:21)
    at http://localhost:9000/scripts/vendor-bundle.js:70122:71
AggregateError  @   aurelia-pal.js:37
invoke  @   aurelia-dependency-injection.js:692
get @   aurelia-dependency-injection.js:52
get @   aurelia-dependency-injection.js:629
(anonymous) @   aurelia-templating.js:4902
Promise.then (async)        
setRoot @   aurelia-framework.js:215
login   @   login.js:23
evaluate    @   aurelia-binding.js:1555
callSource  @   aurelia-binding.js:5275
handleEvent @   aurelia-binding.js:5284
```

Comment: I think this is related to circular reference with commonjs/webpack module resolution. Or at least your code related to `AuthService` import. Are you sure it's `import AuthService from '...'` instead of `import { AuthService } from '...'`?

Comment: Thank you bigopon, your tip led to the solution.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you @bigopon, your tip led to the solution. Writing the import for AuthService as:

```
import {AuthService} from './auth-service';
```

worked. I reviewed the relevant doc for import from MDN [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import). If in 'auth-service.js' I had used

```
export default AuthService {...
```

then

```
import AuthService from './auth-service;
```

would work.  However, I don't understand why the error from the line in login.js

```
this.app.setRoot('app');
```

caused the error rather than the previous line. Thanks for your help!